# Old fashioned region method?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

Just stumbled across this idea in http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Mathematica/Volume%20III/Chapter%2015.pdf.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, y_] = 1 - x^2 + y^2;
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1 + x^2},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 FillingStyle -> LightBlue,
 PlotRange -> {0, 4},
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Which produces:

[image]

My main question is related specifically to

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1 + x^2}],
```

the `{y,x,1+x^2}` part.

I am so used to using RegionFunction to perform this task. I went into the documentation for Plot3D to see if I could find an example of this, but I could not find anything like this. Is this an old fashioned way that will soon disappear? Is this something I should share with my students? It's amazing how it matches the associated double integral:

$$\int_0^1\int_x^{x^2}(1-x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx$$

I also have a second question on this image, if folks don't mind. See how the zeros on the tick marks on the x- and z-axes overlap. Anyone have a simple way of separating them a bit?

Comment: @belisarius I've updated my post because I think I wasn't making it specific enough on what I was focusing on.

Comment: you question seems to only be about the limit specification? It seems you are correct that this is not mentioned in the `Plot3D` documentation, but it is pretty much standard convention among similar functions that take multidimensional ranges that reading left to right the limits of each variable can depend on those before it (`Table`, `Integrate`, etc ).  No need to be concerned it should go away.

Comment: @george2079 Yes, the worry was about the limit specification. Thanks for your reply. You seem confident that it will continue to exist.

Comment: Great question!  I don't think I have ever used this `Plot3D` form myself even though I knew it could be used elsewhere as george2079 remarks.

Comment: Re ticks: `Plot3D[1 - x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1 + x^2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.08]`?

Answer (score 10):

I will post this to avoid confusion - region has a new meaning in WL since [Geometric Computation](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geometric-computation/) was introduced in V10.

Relative to that meaning what you showed is not a WL region because you cannot compute over it, but of course is a visual of some *mathematical* region defined analytically and shown with help of `Filling`.

To achieve the same via *computable* region:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[0<z<1-x^2+y^2 && x<y<1+x^2 && 0<x<1, {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[R, PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}]
```

[image]

```
Volume[R]
```

> 29/21

```
Integrate[1 - x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1 + x^2}]
```

> 29/21

```
Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] R]
N[%]
```

> 29/21
>
> 1.380952380952381`

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] R]
```

> 1.3809523809015896`

The above shows that WL computable regions enable symbolic and numeric computations over them.

Comment: Thanks for this very interesting example. Very well explained.